# Trap on DEBUG signal for the ash and dash shells?

Tags: shell, debugging, trap, dash, ash

With the bash shell, you can install a trap on the synthetic DEBUG signal. This is useful and will execute your function or bit of code on every shell command.

Not so in ash or dash.

```
$ trap 'echo hi' DEBUG
-ash: trap: DEBUG: invalid signal specification
```

Are there any alternatives to achieve the same result with the ash shell?